# Starting a syn region with a keyword

Tags: vim

I would like to start a region with "virtual" to highlight all virtual methods with a different color, but being virtual already defined as keyword in the cpp.vim file, the region matching is never performed. I tried the following

```
syn region   cVirtualMethod   start="virtual" end=";" contains=cppType
hi cVirtualMethod ctermfg=red
```

but it does not work. It does however, if I remove virtual from cppType, but it highlights the whole line (fair enough, I'd prefer just the method name, but it's good as well).

Is there a way of leaving the cpp.vim virtual highlight (so virtual will end up green) and highlight just the method name ?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax keywords always take precedence over regions, so there's no way around removing `virtual` as a syntax keyword.

You can maintain the highlighting by defining a highlight group for the region start (and not the end; that's the reason for the reverse argument order):

```
:syn region   cVirtualMethod end=";" matchgroup=cppType start="\<virtual\>"
```

Still, the entire inner region will be highlighted. To avoid that, you can add a contained `:syn-match` that matches only the method name, contain it in the above region, and put the `:highlight` on that instead of the region.

Answer (score 0):

can you test if this works for you?

```
hi! virtualMethod ctermfg=red
call matchadd("virtualMethod", "virtual.*;")
```

if it does, you can add autocmd for that `matchadd` call

Comment: btw, I like your "Least Astonishment" Q!

Comment: This looks like a clever trick, but I think the different scopes (buffer for `:syn` vs. window for `matchadd()`) make this impractical.

Comment: @IngoKarkat could you please explain a bit the difference of `hi` on the two scopes, sometime I get confused about it. thanks in advance. I thought with `au` eg. `BufWinEnter` call `matchadd` would be ok... :(

Comment: When you open another buffer in the same window, the syntax changes, but your `matchadd()` would persist (unless you define another autocmd to `matchdelete()`... and now it gets tedious!

Comment: I think I got it. thank so it is somehow "global" highlighting... thank you.. @IngoKarkat