# How can I use different colors for virtual and virtual pure methods?

Tags: c++, vim

I am trying to get different colors for virtual and pure virtual methods, like this

```
syn region   cppVirtualPureMethod   start="virtual" end="= 0;"
syn region   cppVirtualMethod   start="virtual" end="[;{]"
```

unfortunately, the selection is performed only using the start identifier, so it cannot disambiguate between the two cases. Is there some vim trick to obtain what I need?

Comment: Try start="virtual.*= 0;" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523282/starting-a-syn-region-with-a-keyword does this Q help you?

Comment: @brian because of the way we format the code, it's not guaranteed to be on the same line, so that won't work. I need a region

Comment: @Kent: I asked that question, but no. The case is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already found out, `:syn region` only considers the `start=` portion for a match. You have to use `:syn match` (potentially with a costly regular expression that matches across lines) to include the differentiating end.

In general (considering that you've attempted [something similar beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523282/starting-a-syn-region-with-a-keyword)), such elaborate highlighting is difficult to do in Vim, whose syntax parsing is designed for broad applicability and 80/20-correctness, not exact grammar representations. If you really need such fine nuances displayed in different visual styles (especially for C++, which has a *very* complex grammar), I'd rather use an IDE with a proper parser for the full language.

Comment: I'd love to, but eclipse vim plugin is not as good as the real thing :(